# Datepicker Issue in Visual workflow

Tags: visual-workflow, date, user, locale, date-picker

I have my user "locale" set as **Korean**.  There is simple visual workflow with a 'date' type field.

[image]

And when choosing the date in the flow, it gives the error *Invalid Date*

[image]

Though the dates are correct.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

The problem is the user locale.  From salesforce user guides I found that the date format for Korean locale is "**2008. 2. 28 PM 4:30**"

How do I change this in a flow to save it in this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no straight away solution for this problem.

We are just using en_US locales for now, until Salesforce comes up with something